# How to disable app's audio being recorded in C#

Tags: c#, audio, voice, recording

How can I avoid user from being able to record app's audio in C#?
It's due to some copyright issues and must be done in my project.

Comment: What way(s) are you expecting the user to record?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with this but it sounds like you need to ensure compliance; I'd start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/playready-client-sdk

Comment: @zcui93 I want to prevent other applications on the same computer from recording my application's sounds

Comment: @AlexPaven Thanks! that seems to be a pretty good refrence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this isn't possible. If you can hear something, you can record it. Obviously that process would be lossy, but there is absolutely nothing you can do to prevent it (the laws of physics say so).

I should clarify that it appears not to be possible to prevent digital recording via WASAPI on windows machines, either. Even if this was possible, it would not be possible to prevent someone plugging in their own sound card which supports digital recording (and some do).

Comment: Though this is correct, it might be feasible (but probably incredible hard and depending on OS/etc.) to prevent other programs running on the same computer recording that audio. For all I know there are ways to flag an audio stream sent to the audio card in a way that the OS would prevent this. But prevent recording equipment from recording the sound waves? No, not possible.

Comment: Also, it appears not to be possible to block digital recording of the generated sound (you can use WASAPI to do this, even if your sound hardward doesn't support it - and if your sound hardware doesn't support it, you can replace with hardware which does etc...)

Comment: You're right, but I just want to prevent other programs running on the same computer recording that audio. Just like @LasseVågsætherKarlsen said.

Comment: @AdamBrown they wanted to prevent softwares from audio recording. We know we can't control hardware.